# error in xml parsing in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

I am making progress-bar in android but in progssbar_clip.xml file I get following error

```
#error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element  progressbar_progress_clip.xml   /progressbar/res/layout line 9  Android AAPT Problem
```

and below is .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<clip
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_progressing"
android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="left"/>

<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="94" >

        <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pBarOverallStatus"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:indeterminateOnly="false"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_progress_clip" >
            </ProgressBar>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ringLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/status_bar_ring"
                android:src="@drawable/status_bar_ring" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ringRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/status_bar_ring"
                android:src="@drawable/status_bar_ring" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

how can I slove it?

Comment: post layout code of `progressbar_progress_clip` too!

Answer (score 3):

your XML layout can have only one root element so you should do the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="94" >

//everything else goes here ....



</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope that helps .

Answer (score 0):

your xml have ambiguity of root as you have two elements `clip` and `relativelayout` at the same level

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:oriantation="vertical"
            >
    <clip
          android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_progressing"
          android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
          android:gravity="left"/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="94" >

        <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pBarOverallStatus"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:indeterminateOnly="false"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_progress_clip" >
            </ProgressBar>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ringLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/status_bar_ring"
                android:src="@drawable/status_bar_ring" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ringRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/status_bar_ring"
                android:src="@drawable/status_bar_ring" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```